# Solve $ x=54+\sqrt{54-\sqrt{x}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried so much with this equation but nothing seems to work:
$$ x=54+\sqrt{54-\sqrt{x}} $$
I tried squaring but it gives a quadratic equation that I can't solve.
Any ideas please?

Comment: You should square it **twice** to get a quartic equation. If you throw that equation to a CAS, you will find the quartic equation factors into a pair of quadratic equation.  You have only 4 numbers to test whether it is indeed solution of your equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

Comment: Numerically it's about 60.8

Comment: Do you want real solutions?

Comment: If the solution was some integer, or easy guessable number, there would be a simple way to proceed : $x - 54$ is a monoteously increasing function, and $\sqrt{54 - \sqrt{x}}$ is decreasing, so if the solution exists, it would be unique, and guessing the one solution,  one solves the equation. However, in this case solution is not beatufil $x \simeq 60.8$.

Comment: @spiridon beauty is in the eye of the beholder. The solution is $x=(107+\sqrt{213})/2$, which is quite beautiful. For one thing, it's of degree two, where one would expect it to be of degree four. For another thing, it's a perfect square (in the ring of integers in ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{213})$), it's the square of $(1+\sqrt{213})/2$, so $\sqrt x$ has degree two, where you might expect it to have degree eight.

Comment: @GerryMyerson that's amazing!

Answer (score 8):

$$ x = 54 + \sqrt{54 - \sqrt{x}} \\ k = 54 - \sqrt{x} \\ t = x-54 \\ k+t = x - \sqrt{x}$$

And so:

$$ t = \sqrt{k} \\ t^2 = k \\ t^2 + t = t(t+1) = k+t = x - \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x}( \sqrt{x} - 1)$$

$$t = \sqrt{x} -1 ~~ \text{and} ~~ t+1 = \sqrt{x} $$

$$ t = x-54 \\ (t+1)^2 = x \\ (x-53)^2 = x$$

Which is a simple quadratic equation, you will get $2$ results, one of them would not be correct because it would make the LHS of your equation negative (after you "move" the 54 to the left), and we know square-roots over the reals give a positive solution.

Comment: +1 interesting approach.

Comment: You've gone from $a(a+1)=b(b+1)$ to $a=b$, but this is not necessarily correct, e.g., $(3)(4)=(-4)(-3)$ but $3\ne-4$.

Comment: Hey mate! @GerryMyerson Look at the equation: $a(a+1) = b(b-1)$ we, of course cannot deduce that straight away, but looking further, using the quadratic formula, we get the desired solutions (for $a_1, a_2$ or for $b_1,b_2$ )

Comment: It's OK here, though, since $a(a+1)=b(b+1)$ does imply $a=b$ if we know $a>0$ and $b>0$, and in this problem we certainly have $t>0$ and $\sqrt x-1>0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Certainly $t= \sqrt x -1$ is a solution of $t(t+1) = \sqrt x ( \sqrt x -1)$ and we get a solution for $x$. Even if there would be also other solutions of $t(t+1) = \sqrt x ( \sqrt x -1)$ (which is not the case in the present situation), this could not produce another solution for $x$. See spiridon_the_sun_rotator's comment the question.

Comment: @Paul there *is* another solution to $t(t+1)=\sqrt x(\sqrt x-1)$, namely, $t=-\sqrt x$, $t+1=1-\sqrt x$. That solution doesn't lead to a solution of the original problem, but that doesn't mean you're correct to omit any mention of it. The correct thing to do is to mention both solutions, and then say why one of them doesn't lead to a solution of the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

We can put $y=54-\sqrt{x}$ to get a system of equations
\begin{align}
x-54&=\sqrt{y}\\
y-54&=-\sqrt{x}.
\end{align}
Squaring and subtracting from each other (using the fact that $x,y \geq 0$) this simplifies to
$$
(y-x)(108-x-y)=y-x.
$$
Since $y \neq x$ (otherwise the system above would yield $-\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}$ and so $x=y=0$, impossible), we have $108-x-y=1$. Plugging that into one of the equations we get $x-54=\sqrt{107-x}$, and so we need to solve the quadratic equation
$$
(x-54)^2=107-x.
$$
That should be a straightforward exercise yielding two real roots only one of which will satisfy $x -54 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

With $x=t^2$, $$(t^2-54)^2=54-t$$ is a quartic equation.

Though a CAS tells us the the solutions have a relatively simple expression, I see no better way to reach it than the standard resolution method of the quartic.

Comment: As @achille noted in the first comment on the question, you can get a quartic that factors (over the rationals) into a product of two quadratics, so one can avoid the method one would have to use for irreducible quartics.